# Python Speech Recognition :- AttributeError: module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'Recognizer'

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

```
This File is saved as abc.py

#import pyaudio
#Tried import pyaudio

import speech_recognition as sr

r=sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("say anything")
    audio=r.listen(source)
    try:
        text=r.recognize_google(audio)

        #text=r.google_recognize(audio)
        #Tried text=r.google_recognize(audio)

        print("you said : {}".format(text))
    except:
            print("can't recognize what you said")
```

I except successful compilation and execution of this code, but the actual output is :-
**r=sr.Recognizer()
AttributeError: module 'speech_recognition' has no attribute 'Recognizer'**

> **I have run this program in python IDLE 3.7.3(64 bit), should i run in spyder version 3.7.3(64 bit) or in visual studio, if in visual
>   studio what should be it's version ?**

Comment: What is your .py file name? If the file is speech_recognition.py and python is looking not to the speech_recognition module but search the Recognizer in your module (file). In that case You need simple to rename your module (file).

Comment: @Shubhaditya so you have a python file with name 'speech_recognition' , in that file , 'Recognizer()' function is missing. check 'speech_recognition.py' file